# How I can set Locale in Session scope in sailsjs

Tags: express, sails.js

since req scope changes in every request I want set locale in session scope, can I do that? and how I can?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `express-session` .

**Init config :**

```
var app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

**Example :**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```